# Not Able to fetch data from twitter

Tags: java, twitter

I am trying to fetch data from twitter using streaming API and i am using basic authentication. But i am getting 401 error which is basically for wrong user name or password. Below is my code . Also I have given the error that i am getting console. Will any one please tell me what mistake i am doing .

**Code**

```
package org.hi.hello;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.ConnectException;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.util.Map;

import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;

public class TwitterGetter {

    public static void getTweetStream(String Tokey) throws  InterruptedException, IOException{


        URL tweetCon = new URL("https://stream.twitter.com/1/statuses/filter.json?track="+Tokey);
        URLConnection openTweetCon = tweetCon.openConnection();
        String login = "priya.XXXXX@gmail.com:XXX123";
        String encoding = new String( Base64.encodeBase64(login.getBytes())) ;//((login.getBytes()));
        openTweetCon.setRequestProperty("Authorization",  encoding);
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(openTweetCon.getInputStream()));

        String inputLine;




        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
        {
            System.out.println(inputLine);
        }


            //basicDbObject.put("text", JSONObject.fromString(inputLine).get("text"));
            //coll.save(basicDbObject);

    }



    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        Boolean Cont = true;
        cont:
        do {
            try
            {

        getTweetStream("Trip,trip,games,futball,amex,creditcard,citibank,mastercard,vacation,electronics,train,americanexpress,platinumcard,visacredit");
            }catch (IOException e){System.err.println("Connection Error");  System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            System.out.println(e.getStackTrace());}
            catch (Exception e){System.err.println("Encountered Exception: Restarting"); continue cont;}}while (Cont==true);}


    }
```

**Error in console**

```
Connection Error
Server returned HTTP response code: 401 for URL: https://stream.twitter.com/1/statuses/filter.json?track=Trip,trip,games,futball,amex,creditcard,citibank,mastercard,vacation,electronics,train,americanexpress,platinumcard,visacredit
[Ljava.lang.StackTraceElement;@1089cc5e
Connection Error
Server returned HTTP response code: 401 for URL: https://stream.twitter.com/1/statuses/filter.json?track=Trip,trip,games,futball,amex,creditcard,citibank,mastercard,vacation,electronics,train,americanexpress,platinumcard,visacredit
[Ljava.lang.StackTraceElement;@3d0bbf9e
Connection Error
Server returned HTTP response code: 401 for URL: https://stream.twitter.com/1/statuses/filter.json?track=Trip,trip,games,futball,amex,creditcard,citibank,mastercard,vacation,electronics,train,americanexpress,platinumcard,visacredit
[Ljava.lang.StackTraceElement;@77ce3fc5
Connection Error
Server returned HTTP response code: 401 for URL: https://stream.twitter.com/1/statuses/filter.json?track=Trip,trip,games,futball,amex,creditcard,citibank,mastercard,vacation,electronics,train,americanexpress,platinumcard,visacredit
[Ljava.lang.StackTraceElement;@5fe0f2f6
```

Comment: Twitter APIv1.0 has been retired (https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1). Also basic auth is not support. Check: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/deprecations/spring-2012

Comment: Thanks Vishal for reply, i am new to twiteer API, will you please tell me if in API 1.1 basic auth is supported ? . I just changed the URL like https://stream.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/filter.json?track="+Tokey , but still i am getting same error . Please suggest any work arround . Thanks alot !!

Comment: No, basic auth is not supported anymore. For python you can start with  a library like https://code.google.com/p/python-twitter/ or tweepy. I use the python oauth library from simplegeo and call the APIs directly for more control but starting off with python-twitter helped initially to get started fast and understand the details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twitter APIv1.0 has been retired. Check [this](http://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1).

Twitter does not support Basic Auth anymore. Check [this](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/moving-basic-auth-oauth).

For python starting off with a twitter library that supports oauth would get you off the blocks quick. [python-twitter](https://github.com/bear/python-twitter) and [tweepy](https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy) seem fairly widely used with several stackoverflow supporters.

I used python-twitter initially and it helped get started quickly and understand the details before moving to call the Twitter1.1 APIs directly using [simplegeo's oauth](https://github.com/simplegeo/python-oauth2) library for more control.

Comment: Thanks Vishal for help, now i am able to connect to twitter using oauth . I am using twiteer4j :) Thanks !!